# What's the benefits of using a design document?

Tags: view, couchbase

While reading Couchbase document, I've came across the following.

> Because the index for each map/reduce combination within each view
>   within a given design document is updated at the same time, avoid
>   declaring too many views within the same design document

http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-writing.html

If that's the case, why does it even allow you to add more than one views into a design document? Should I simply create one view per design document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping multiple views together under one design document is useful when the data being indexed by the views is related and when having the related indexes updated at the same time is desired.

For example take the 'beer sample' bucket that is distributed with Couchbase. It includes two types of documents, one type for breweries and one for beers. You can create a bunch of views on both of these document types. Say you have four views that achieve the following:

- List all beers
- List all breweries
- List all beers under a certain abv
- List all breweries in a country

So essentially we have two views that operate on documents related to breweries and another two that operate on beers. At this point is it very useful to group the related views together under one design document because it means they will both be updated at the same time. If you were to add a new brewery, both the view that lists all breweries *and* the view that lists all breweries in a country will have updates triggered at the same time. On the other hand, if you were to have these two views in separate design docs you would end up triggering two separate view updates, which will mean increased response time if you are using stale=false or potentially inconsistent results if you are not.

Whether this is useful in any given dataset depends on each implementation, how related the documents are and how important response times are. Couchbase gives you the option to tune the view updates to meet your requirements.

An additional reason is that you can control the automated [index update triggers](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-operation.html) on a per design document basis, so you can have some views updated more regularly than others.

The wiki page on [Couchbase View Engine Internals](http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Couchbase+View+Engine+Internals) may be of interest to you as it explains the design document concept quite well and provides some further insight about how tasks are delegated to design documents by the view engine.